# iOS6: Twitter SetInitialText Not Working

Tags: ios, twitter, xamarin.ios, ios6

I have just updated my application to iOS 6, and the `SetInitialText` function of the `TWTweetComposeViewController` has stopped working. The composer just comes up empty. I am using MonoTouch, has anyone else seen this issue? The same code still works fine on my iOS 5 device.

Answer (score 1):

This works as expected for me with the following code:

```
var button2 = UIButton.FromType (UIButtonType.RoundedRect);
button2.Frame = new RectangleF (0f, 0f, 300f, 40f);
button2.SetTitle ("Tweet!", UIControlState.Normal);
button2.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => {
    var tvc = new TWTweetComposeViewController ();
    tvc.SetInitialText ("Here is a tweet...");
    tvc.SetCompletionHandler ((result) => {
        if (result == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult.Cancelled) {
            Console.WriteLine ("Cancelled sending the tweet!");
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine ("Tweet sent! hurrah!");  
        }
        this.DismissModalViewControllerAnimated (true);
    });
    this.PresentModalViewController (tvc, true);
};
View.AddSubview (button2);
```

Even though PresentModal and DismissModal are deprecated, do you have any example code of the problem?

Comment: Thank you for the example, I have resolved by problem by instantiating the TWTweetComposeViewController directly instead of implementing it in a new view controller.

Comment: Feel free to mark the question as answered so others know that the question has a successful response :)